# For XML structure with two parent nodes and multiple child nodes?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I need the XML to be structured like this:

```
   <Loans>
    <Loan>
       <GUID></GUID>
       <LoanFolder></LoanFolder>
       <LastModified></LastModified>
       <TotalMonthlyPayment></TotalMonthlyPayment>
       <AgentCompanyName></AgentCompanyName>
    <LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
       <LoanSecondaryStatus>
          <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
          <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
        </LoanSecondaryStatus>
       <LoanSecondaryStatus>
        <StatusName>Name</StatusName>
        <StatusDate>Date</StatusDate>
       </LoanSecondaryStatus>
    </LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
 </Loan>
</Loans>
```

I have a FOR XML query that is structured like this:

```
    SELECT 
  [GUID] 
  ,[LOANFOLDER]
  ,[LASTMODIFIED]
  ,[LASTIMPORTED]
  ,[TotalMonthlyPayment]
  ,[AgentCompanyName],
   (
   SELECT 
    'Borrower Docs Sent/Req' as 'StatusName',
    CASE WHEN t.BorrowerDocsSent IS NOT NULL THEN t.BorrowerDocsSent ELSE '' END as 'StatusDate'

FROM Encompass_loanData as t
WHERE t.[GUID] = E.[GUID]
FOR XML PATH('LoanSecondaryStatus'), TYPE
  ),
  (
   SELECT 
    t.BorrowerCity as 'StatusName',
    t.[GUID] as 'StatusDate'

FROM Encompass_loanData as t
WHERE t.[GUID] = E.[GUID]
FOR XML PATH('LoanSecondaryStatus'), TYPE
  )

From Encompass_loanData E
WHERE [LASTMODIFIED] >= '20160121'
FOR XML PATH ('Loan'), type, root('Loans')
```

This is getting me close, but is missing the top "LoanSecondaryStatusDates" root node. How can I add this root node in?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d672a/2/0

Note:  I was able to add the node using this XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Loan">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(self::LoanSecondaryStatus)]"/>
            <LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="LoanSecondaryStatus"/>
            </LoanSecondaryStatusDates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com/? FYI, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2998271)

Comment: Here you go - hopefully this helps.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d672a/2/0

Comment: Well I didn't figure out how to do this with FOR XML, but I was able to apply XSL.

Comment: posted possible pure SQL alternative to produce the desired XML structure, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible SQL query, built according to your SQL Fiddle table structure, that will produce the desired XML format :

```
SELECT 
       [GUID] 
      ,[LOANFOLDER]
      ,[LASTMODIFIED]
      ,[LASTIMPORTED]
      ,[TotalMonthlyPayment]
      ,[AgentCompanyName]
      ,(
        SELECT * FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), t.TotalMonthlyPayment) as 'StatusName',
                t.[GUID] as 'StatusDate'

            FROM [Sample] as t
            WHERE t.[GUID] = E.[GUID]
            UNION
            SELECT 
                'Borrower Docs Sent/Req' as 'StatusName',
                CASE WHEN t.LastModified IS NOT NULL THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), t.LastModified, 126) ELSE '' END as 'StatusDate'

            FROM [Sample] as t
            WHERE t.[GUID] = E.[GUID]
        ) AS s
        FOR XML PATH('LoanSecondaryStatus'), TYPE, root('LoanSecondaryStatusDates')
       )

From [Sample] E
FOR XML PATH ('Loan'), type, root('Loans')
```

**<kbd>[`sqlfiddle demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d672a/3)</kbd>**

Basically, the inner `FOR XML PATH` will return `LoanSecondaryStatus` elements wrapped in one `LoanSecondaryStatusDates` parent, and a `UNION` clause used to generate `LoanSecondaryStatus` data. Apart from that, all the conversions seen in the above query are needed to make both sides of the `UNION` return compatible data types, otherwise the query will terminates with conversion error.

Comment: Nice.  I think the union to generate the LoanSecondaryStatus data was the missing element. Thanks!