# How to format XML code when data is coming in one line

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have sample data

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (users int, ts int, name varchar(10), [1] int);

INSERT INTO @Table1 (users, ts, name, [1])
VALUES (1, 1, 'Raj', 0),
       (1, 3, 'maj', 2534),
       (1, 10, 'yes', 1458);
```

Script

```
select
    'test' as 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode',
    users AS 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode',
    name as 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode' 
from 
    @Table1
where 
    ts = 1
for xml path('xmlexecute'), elements;
```

Output :

```
<xmlexecute>
  <job>
    <branch>
      <FBEN>
        <opcode>test1Raj</opcode>
      </FBEN>
    </branch>
  </job>
</xmlexecute>
```

How can I get like this instead?

```
<xmlexecute>
  <job>
    <branch>
      <FBEN>
        <opcode>test1Raj</opcode>
        <opcode>1</opcode>
        <opcode>Raj</opcode>
      </FBEN>
    </branch>
  </job>
</xmlexecute>
```

If I'm trying to add

```
select
    'test' as 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode',
    users AS 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode',
    name as 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode',
    [1] AS 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode/1'   
from 
    @Table1
where 
    ts = 3
for xml path('xmlexecute'), elements;
```

I get an error:

> Msg 6850, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Column name 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode/1' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; '1'(0x0031) is the first character at fault.

Comment: Check this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34938591/for-xml-structure-with-two-parent-nodes-and-multiple-child-nodes

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (users int, ts int, name varchar(10), [1] int);

INSERT INTO @Table1 (users, ts, name, [1])
VALUES (1, 1, 'Raj', 0),
       (1, 3, 'maj', 2534),
       (1, 10, 'yes', 1458);
select
(
    select
        'test' as [opcode]
        ,''
        ,users AS [opcode]
        ,''
        ,name as [opcode] 
        ,''
        ,[1] AS [opcode]
    from 
        @Table1
    where 
        ts = 1
    for xml path('FBEN'),ROOT('branch'),TYPE
) AS job
FOR XML PATH('xmlexecute')
;
```

The empty nodes `,''` between your `opcode` nodes tell the XML engine: *This node is finished, start a new one.* This is needed, if you want to place several nodes with the same name one below each other.

The result

```
<xmlexecute>
  <job>
    <branch>
      <FBEN>
        <opcode>test</opcode>
        <opcode>1</opcode>
        <opcode>Raj</opcode>
        <opcode>0</opcode>
      </FBEN>
    </branch>
  </job>
</xmlexecute>
```

Comment: i need to check this solution in my requirement @shnugo

Comment: what about the 4th column I;m still getting the same error while using the 4th

Comment: @mohan111 I don't know, what you did, but see my update. It's working... Your `XPath` in the question (`[1] AS 'job/branch/FBEN/opcode/1`) cannot work. An elementsname must not start with a number. That is, what the error tells you. The *expected output* in your question does not inlcude this column... Don't know, how and where you want to find it...

Comment: @mohan111 btw: According to your title *how-to-format-xml-code-when-data-is-coming-in-one-line* my answer solves this question... I wanted to tell you, that you should place a new question how to deal with your column `[1]`, but you've done so already (and I've answered there too). You took away the acceptance, which feels a bit harsh...